# Android: Technique to fade a edit-text field

Tags: android, user-interface

I was wondering what the best way to fade out a edit text field programmatically?

For example I would like the edit text field to look something like this:

[image]

Currently I am just using static images that I fade out using gimp, but I would to change them all to faded edit text fields.

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve similar result with gradient.

First create in drawable forlder xml file with `shape` element, for example:

```
<!-- mygradient.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="@color/black" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="@color/grey"
        android:endColor="@color/white"
        android:startColor="@color/black"
        android:type="linear" />

</shape>
```

Next use your xml as background for some view:

```
<TextView
    android:background="@drawable/mygradient"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

For more info about shape drawable and gradients look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)

Comment: Ok thank you, this is a great start. I am currently skinning each edit text box using android:background. How can I achieve the fading effect on the skinned edit text box? hopefully this questions makes sense to you lol

Comment: Could You post simple xml with one of that "skinned" EditTexts?

Comment: <EditText android:id="@+id/skinnedbox"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/myskin" />

Comment: I'm not sure. Try to wrap `EditText` into layout and use skin for alayout and shape for `EditText` or use `shape` together with other xml attributes like `android:drawableTop`, `android:drawableBottom` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a much easier answer to this, and it is built into the controls. It is hard to tell if this is exactly what you wanted due to the extremely small picture size.

I found this when I was trying to find more information on fading the EditTexts, so I thought I would share things I already knew since the accepted answer is very complex

```
EditText textbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textbox);

// This enables the fading automatically. 
// Use Horizontal if you want the sides to fade!
textbox.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);  

// This allows you to change to depth of the fade
// Low values like 10 has an incredible small fade, but values like 100 seem to be really good!
textbox.setFadingEdgeLength(100);
```